# Translation of 要領が悪い

Tags: translation, words

I'm struggling a bit with the meaning of 要領｛ようりょう｝ in this sentence I encountered:

> 私は仕事の要領が悪いので、いつも残業になってしまう。

I know that the literal translation (while there are several) of 要領 would be something along the lines of the outline, or the "knack" of things. When I try to translate this sentence it comes out like this:

> Because I'm clumsy at work, I always end up working overtime.

Would this interpretation be somewhat correct? I am particularly unsure what to do about the particle のthat precedes 要領 - in my head, I want to say に instead of の, which probably has something to do with wanting a too literal translation.

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/要領が良い

Answer (score 1, accepted):

要領 here is a noun. Literately, 仕事の要領 means "this job's critical(required) skill". Using に would not be correct here.

This sentence implies that "I" did not get the right or most efficient way of doing this work, so I always work overtime.